# Perform function when a JTextField is 'filled' to a certain character limit

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

What listener can I use to make a function happen once a certain number of characters are entered into a `JTextField`?

```
JTextField txtF=new JTextField();
char[] txtIn=txtF.getText().toCharArray();
if(txtIn.length()==5){
//perform action here
}
```

I tried `keyPressed` but it wants me to press enter to check for char length.

Answer (score 3):

[DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) is probably the most comprehensive way.